# My code causes the page to jump when internal link is clicked :(

Tags: html, css

Ok I have set up this little box with links above it, if you click this link to see:
(you may need to scroll down a bit)
http://coffeemachines4u.co.uk/coffeemachines4u.co.uk/window.html

If you click the grey boxes the content under them will change, which is what I was trying to achieve. But my problem is that the page will also jump once a link is clicked. I would prefer this not to happen, I want the page and scrollbar to stay in the same place. Can anybody see a way around this?

I tried to implement jquery while looking at some past questions that are similar but I have only just started jquery on codeacademy and do not know much about it yet :/

Sorry I have tried for 15 mins to try and get my code to display on here but its not working :/

Comment: What browser are you using? Im on chrome and there doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: Hello, I am using Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding return false to the anchor tag which should stop the scrolling:

```
<a href="#upload" class="nav" onclick="return false;"></a>
```